# How can I make my react router active route classname DRY

Tags: reactjs, react-router, dry

How do I stop the repetition of the `nav-btn` class in my react project?

I am using `react-router-dom` v6.

```
<NavLink
  to="/"
  className={(navInfo) => navInfo.isActive
    ? 'nav-btn bg-green-700 text-white'
    : 'nav-btn'
  }
>
  Home
</NavLink>
```

[The picture given below](https://ibb.co/0FnXRVP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that could be solved via a wrapper component, try this:

```js
    function MyCustomNavLink({to, navInfo, children}) {
      return <NavLink to={to} classname={navInfo.isActive ? 'nav-btn bg-green-700 text-white' : 'nav-btn'}>{children}</NavLink>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean *specifically* the `"nav-btn"` CSS classname, then I suggest passing your classes in an array and filtering what is active/truthy.

Example:

```
<NavLink
  to="/"
  className={({ isActive }) =>
    [
      "nav-btn",
      isActive ? "bg-green-700 text-white" : null,
    ]
      .filter(Boolean)
      .join(" ")
  }
>
  Home
</NavLink>
```

An alternative is to use a utility to make working with and conditionally applying classnames. [Classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) is a good package to use.

Example:

```
import classnames from 'classnames';

...

<NavLink
  to="/"
  className={({ isActive }) => classnames(
    "nav-btn",
    isActive ? "bg-green-700 text-white" : null,
  )}
>
  Home
</NavLink>
```